# Lilypond - two voices, with overlapping beams

Tags: guitar, lilypond

I have the following in my measure:

[image]

What would I have to write, to have those `<c e>`'s connected with beam instead of `1/8` rests, and those in second voice bellow also?

**Edit**

upper voice : `<c' e>8[ r8 <c e>] r8 |`
lower voice : `r8 g[ r8 g] |` ,did connect them:

[image]

however, I am not shure if those rests should still be there in between?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want a beam between the c/e as they are, with the rest still in between? So the actual music isn't changing - just adding a beam?

Comment: see my edit please..

Comment: I'm still confused by what your question is I'm afraid! Your edit is perfectly valid music - if that's what you mean?

Comment: Ok, now please tell me do I have to do this always like this manually, or is there some kind of override which would apply this kind of style for a few measures?

Comment: I'm not sure myself, sorry!

Comment: @branquito yes, you should enter in beams like this manually every time you need it that way since there is no way to automatically beam over rests... also it is proper for the rests should be there, but if you want to hide them it is also OK. You can use `\hideNotes`

Answer (score 4):

The `Auto_beam_engraver` does not beam over rests, bar lines, manual beams or breathing signs.

The [Notation Reference](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/beams#automatic-beams) is quite explicit regarding the beaming across rests: "Beams must be entered manually if beams are to be extended over rests."

Comment: So you are suggesting I should do it manually every time I need it like that?

Comment: @branquito Yes.